# Synonym for "a puppet with its string cut"

Tags: synonyms

I want another phrase/clause that carries the same meaning as above. I don't want to be reusing the above too many times in my writing.

I tried Google, but it seems my Google fu was insufficient.

There are no problems with "a puppet with its strings cut", but I use it frequently, and would rather avoid overusing it in writing.

The context behind the use was someone collapsing due to a loss of cognitive function subsequent to intense coitus.

I may have other uses, and wouldn't want to write a request every time. I generally use the term to refer to someone collapsing due to a loss of cognitive function.

Comment: Please provide some context and an example sentence with the missing word. There are many interpretations possible for that phrase.

Comment: What's wrong with the phrase you've quoted, and what properties are you hoping the have in the desired phrase/clause?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Think of any words/phrases that you'd use to describe someone who has been released from prison:

> ***unshackle*** *v.* release from chains, or other physical restraints.

Chains, shackles, or strings the word fits all situations where someone is being held against their will.

Other phrases to consider: **set free, liberated, let go**

Comment: +1 I second unshackle and liberated. Choose "unshackle" if your primary emphasis is the physical nature of the process (i.e. some physical constraints being lifted), but choose "liberated" if you want to emphasize the spiritual nature.

Comment: That is one flavor.  *unshackled* connotes free. But a puppet with its strings cut is just a pile of limbs, unable to move or do anything.  That is why we need more info from the OP

Comment: I've edited the question.